# VB GetAsyncKeyState' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature.

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a small program but when running my program in visual studio I get the following error:

> GetAsyncKeyState' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature.

But when I build it to an .exe it runs just fine. But that makes it a bit hard to debug the program.

This is the code snipper that throws the error:

```
            If InGame And Not GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Tab) Then
            If Settings.SkinChangera Then SkinChanger.Skinchanger()
        End If
```

and this is GetAsyncKeyState()

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
```

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAsyncKeyState.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advice you to ***never ever*** look for, or use, `Declare Lib` statements you got from the internet. Most of them out there are for **VB6** and are therefore almost always not fully compatible with VB.NET.

Instead, stick to the solutions that use the [**`DllImport` attribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). The site [**pinvoke.net**](http://pinvoke.net) is a great place to look for P/Invoke declarations. If you can't find a VB.NET version of a P/Invoke declaration, take the C# version and run it through a converter such as [**Telerik**](http://converter.telerik.com).

Having that said, you are receiving the error because the parameter and the return value are not of the correct data types. The [**`GetAsyncKeyState()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)'s parameter should be `Integer` and its return value should be `Short`.

Use the [**`DllImport` version of the function**](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAsyncKeyState.html) instead, with the correct data types, and it should work:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short
End Function
```

**Note:** The [**`System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) is of type `Integer`.